# Erratic behavior of boot receiver

Tags: android

I have a several devices (Minix X68-i) all running the same firmware and software versions.

On some of them my boot receiver works fine, others it rarely works, and a few it's closer to 50-50 whether they will receive the event.

I'm out of ideas as to what could cause the code to work so erratically, other than potentially faulty hardware.

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"
    android:name="com.proreception.displaymanagement.Receiver.BootReceiver"
    android:label="StartMyActivity" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="500" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

BootReceiver

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = "BootReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction()) && constants.ONBOOT) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, FullscreenActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            Log.d(TAG, "Starting Application");
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```